# Unexpected size when a struct has a union

Tags: c, struct, sizeof, structure-packing

I am trying to verify the size of a struct.  For some reasons, it's giving me a size of 18 rather than the expected 14 bytes (the union should have a max of 8 + 2 + 2 = 12 bytes).  Can someone help me?

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) def
{
        union {
                double x;   /* 8 bytes */
                char *y;    /* 8 bytes as for 64-bit system */
                struct {
                        struct def *array; /* 8 bytes */
                        unsigned short a;  /* 2 bytes */
                        unsigned short b;  /* 2 bytes */
                } z;
        } w;
        unsigned short v;  /* 2 bytes */
} DEF, *DEFP;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        printf("size of DEF = %lu\n", sizeof(DEF));
        printf("size of unsigned short = %lu\n", sizeof(unsigned short));
        printf("size of struct def * = %lu\n", sizeof(struct def *));
        printf("size of char * = %lu\n", sizeof(char *));
        printf("size of double = %lu\n", sizeof(double));
}
```

Here's what it displays when I run it:

```
$ gcc test.c && ./a.out
size of DEF = 18
size of unsigned short = 2
size of struct def * = 8
size of char * = 8
size of double = 8
```

Comment: Try to prove your assumptions. Show the size of only the union and of only the inner struct.

Comment: You might be experiencing data structure packing/padding. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment

Comment: Or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119123/why-isnt-sizeof-for-a-struct-equal-to-the-sum-of-sizeof-of-each-member

Comment: What is the layout, i.e. the relative offsets of the parts? Also, you know that things like padding is introduced to provide alignment guarantees for the CPU. Not having these has multiple bad effects, from slowdowns to crashes.

Comment: thanks all! makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__attribute__((__packed__))` refers to `struct def` only. It does not pack the anonymous  `struct` inside the anonymous `union` inside `struct def`.

So most likely those two members

```
                   unsigned short a;  /* 2 bytes */
                   unsigned short b;  /* 2 bytes */
```

"use" 4 but 2 bytes.

---

Unrelated to your question: C mandates to print `size_t`s using the `z` *length modifier*:

```
 printf("size of DEF = %zu\n", sizeof (DEF));
```

Comment: I would've expected 4 bytes of padding at the end of the inner structure.

Comment: 2 bites padding after `unsigned short a;`  lacks consistency  as then there would be 2 bites padding after `unsigned short v;` making size 20.  Go with  [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781938/unexpected-size-when-a-struct-has-a-union#comment84565403_48782010)

Comment: @chux: The 18 you get because the out `struct` *is* packed. I tested this (on cygwin, using gcc 4.9.2 :}) and it's in fact the inner `struct` which, when packed, makes `struct def` shrink from 18 to 14 bytes. Packing the `union`, BTW, does not change anything.

Comment: Curious, with `offsetof(DEF,w.z.b) - offsetof(DEF,w.z.a)` do you get 2 or 4 or ?

Comment: @chux: 1st of all this expression "*Packing the union, BTW, does not change anything*" of mine is wrong, sry for this. 14 bytes I *only* get when packing both, the `union` *and* the inner `struct`. To answer your question: The result of `offsetof(DEF,w.z.b) - offsetof(DEF,w.z.a)` is `2` in of the four possible cases.

Answer (score 2):

Writing:

```
struct foo {
    struct bar {
        ...
    } x;
};
```

Is not different than writing:

```
struct bar { ... };
struct foo {
    struct bar x;
};
```

Why does it matter? It matters because in the second example it should be obvious why the attributes that you apply to `foo` don't automatically apply to `bar`. This means that your outer struct will be packed, but that doesn't change what the components mean.

The inner struct you have will not be packed and it's pretty obvious that if it follows the usual rules of alignment that most architectures follow its size will be a multiple of its most strictly aligned member which will be the pointer. So the size of the struct inside the union will be 16, not 12 as you assumed. Which means that the size of the union will be 16 as well.